# nodejs scss to css failed using npm

Tags: node.js

Trying to execute

```
node-sass --output-style compressed -o css/styles.css scss/styles.cass
```

But getting following error:

myblogs@1.0.0 scss: `node-sass --output-style compressed -o css/styles.css scss/styles.cass`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the myblogs@1.0.0 scss script 'node-sass --output-style compressed -o css/styles.css scss/styles.cass'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the myblogs package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-sass --output-style compressed -o css/styles.css scss/styles.cass
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs myblogs
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls myblogs
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:

any idea ??

node version : v5.6.0
node-sass "version": "3.4.2"
npm version  : 3.6.0

Answer (score 0):

It was spelling mistake !!! 
styles.cass -> styles.scss